# Как сделать резиновый фон

Tags: html, css

Как сделать основной фон резиновым? Например как вот [здесь](http://www.teehanlax.com/).

Comment: Задний фон картинка с большим разрешением как задний фон, в примере реализована через КСС-фреймворк, и блоку фон поставлен и за счет адаптивности меняется фон :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Здравствуйте*

Есть два варианта как решить это

**Вариант 1:**

```
-webkit-background-size: cover; /* Для хрома */
-moz-background-size: cover;  /* Для лисы*/
-o-background-size: cover;  /* Для оперы*/
-ms-background-size: cover;  /* Для ИЭ*/
background-size: cover;  /* Для закрипления*/
```

*или*

**Вариант 2:**

```
background-size: 100% 100%; /* Для всех браузеров сразу  */
```

**Примечание:**

Картинка должна быть большого размера, чтоб потом не терялось качество.

Answer (score 3):

Используется `background-size: cover;`